# when compiling code for usb bootloader for ARM I get fatal error: opening dependency file

Tags: c, arm, cross-compiling, bootloader

I am getting the error opening dependency file. (shown below) I downloaded all the code from sparkfun here https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/94 and it should be compiling. Do you think that this error is caused by windows 10?

```
Compiling C (ARM-only): ../lib/irq.c
    arm-elf-gcc -c -mcpu=arm7tdmi-s -mthumb-interwork -I. -gdwarf-2 -DROM_RUN  -D__WinARM__ -I ../lib/ -Os -Wall -Wcast-align -Wpointer-arith -Wswitch -Wredundant-decls -Wreturn-type -Wshadow -Wunused -Wa,-adhlns=../lib/irq.lst  -I../lib -I../screens -I../LPCUSB -Wcast-qual -MD -MP -MF .dep/irq.o.d -Wnested-externs -Wimplicit -std=gnu99 -Wmissing-prototypes  -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations ../lib/irq.c -o ../lib/irq.o 
    ../lib/irq.c:156: fatal error: opening dependency file .dep/irq.o.d: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    make.exe: *** [../lib/irq.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile this is the line that's failing:

```
-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*)
```

I'm not sure why it is failing for you because it has the leading "-" which should tell it not to fail if the file doesn't exist.

The irq.o.d exists after the first compile of irq.c and contains the header file dependencies for irq.c so that subsequent changes of the headers will cause irq.c to be recompiled. This magic happens because of the GENDEPFLAGS passed to the compiler (-MD etc.).

If '-' doesn't work in your make, you could comment out the include line with a # for the initial compile and then uncomment the line. Or you could leave it commented out and make clean; make every time you change a header file.

Comment: I commented that line out and tried to make clean and got the error below Cleaning project:

rm -f ../Common_WinARM/main.hex
rm -f main.hex
rm -f main.bin
rm -f main.obj
rm -f main.elf
rm -f main.map
rm -f main.obj
rm -f main.a90
rm -f main.sym
rm -f main.lnk
rm -f main.lss
rm -f main.o  syscalls.o 
rm -f  
rm -f 
rm -f 
rm -f 
rm -f Startup.o
rm -f  Startup.lst main.lst  syscalls.lst   
rm -f main.s  syscalls.s
rm -f main.d  syscalls.d
rm -f 
rm -f .dep/*
make.exe: *** [clean_list] Error -1073741502

Comment: Try just make without the make clean. What version of make are you running?

Comment: when I try to make it with that line commented I still get the same error as above. I am running version 4.1.1 (WinARM) and on windows 10

Comment: You have commented it out like this?: "#-include $(shell mkdir .dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard .dep/*) If so then I'm not sure why a simple "make" doesn't work.

Comment: I did the same steps on a windows 7 and it worked, so it must be an issue with windows 10, but I am not sure what would cause this.